# Validate Multiple Emails Comma Separated with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate a string which can be an email or multiple emails separated by commas.

For example:

bill.gates@hotmail.com -> TRUE
bill -> FALSE
bill.gates@microsoft.com,steve.jobs@apple.com" -> TRUE
bill.gates@microsoft.com,steve.jobs@apple.com, bob" -> false
bob,bill.gates@microsoft.com,steve.jobs@apple.com" -> false

I came out with the next code which works with the test cases.

```
function validateEmail(field) {
    var regex=/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i;
    return (regex.test(field)) ? true : false;
}

function validateMultipleEmailsCommaSeparated(value) {
    var result = value.split(",");
    for(var i = 0;i < result.length;i++)
    if(!validateEmail(result[i])) 
            return false;           
    return true;
}
```

Is this the quickest way to do it? What if I want to allow ; and , as separator?

Answer (score 9):

You shouldn't match top-level domains with `[A-Z]{2,4}`:

What about `.museum` or `.travel`? What about IDNA domains like `.xn--0zwm56d` or `.xn--11b5bs3a9aj6g`?

Also, it's perfectly valid to have an email-address like `"John Doe"@example.org`.

In my opinion, all you should check on the client side is if the address contains an `@` and if there's at least one `.` after it. On the server side, you could check if the server exists (you might even want to try connecting to the appropriate SMTP port) or just send out a validation mail.

Everything else is prone to errors as the actual regex to check for valid email addresses [looks like this](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html).

---

Also, this

```
return (regex.test(field)) ? true : false;
```

is a serious WTF - `test()` already returns a boolean value!

---

If you want to allow different separators, use a regular expression instead of a string for splitting, eg

```
value.split(/,|;/)
```

Comment: Suggested edit: "... you should check on the client side is if the address contains ** one and only one ** @ ..." (however, I am presuming that "@" is not allowed in the local-part??)

Comment: @Kristen: '@' is allowed in quoted strings, but only there; I've never seen quoted strings used, though they might provide an easy way to confuse spam bots; one should also keep in mind that the follwoing characters are valid even without quoting: !#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~

Comment: btw, I think I once read that there were even people using mail-addresses with a raw ccTLD domain after the '@'; don't remember which country, though...

Answer (score 3):

Use `var result = value.split(",")`. You end up with an array.

Answer (score 2):

Regex:

```
((\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)*([,])*)*
```

Comment: This regular expression skipped the following case: 
test@test.com, 

Do you have any other solution. its working fine for test@test.com,test1@test.com

Answer (score 1):

In general it is *not* possible to validate email addresses. Something that is syntactically valid does not necessarily go anywhere, and even if it does whether it will be read.

And even then, covering all the possible syntactically correct addresses (according to the applicable RFC) needs an extremely complex regex (see 1st edition of "Mastering Regular Expressions" (Friedl, O'Reilly) for the 4724 or 6598 character versions, and these probably don't handle IDNs). E.g. an apostrophe is a valid character in the local part, and you can have comments inside the email.

Answer (score 1):

```
let emails = 'test@gmail.com, test2@gmail.com';
```

It is very simple. You need to just split your array by comma.

By using,

```
const arrayOfEmail = emails.split(',');
```

Then you should validate the string using regex,

```
const pattern = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;

// Make common function for check single array pattern
export const validateEmailByString = (email: string) => {
  const emailId = email.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r| )/gm, ''); // remove blank spaces and new line breaks from string.
  return emailPattern.test(emailId);
}
```

Then you should just check the emails using,

```
const isAllEmailValid = arrayOfEmail.every(validateEmailByString);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about splitting the string into an array and looping through it passing just one e-mail address at a time?

Answer (score 0):

I used validationEngine and underscore.js to do this:

```
function validateEmail(field, rules, i, options) {
if (!_.all(field.val().split(","), function(candidate) { return $.trim(candidate).match(options.allrules.email.regex); } ))
    return options.allrules.email.alertText;
}
```

And then decorated my form field with:

```
<input class="validate[required,funcCall[validateEmail]]" type="text" name="contact_email" id="contact_email" value=""  />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would throw an `$.trim(result[i])` into that `validateMultipleEmailsCommaSeparated` function as many people will add the space after their comma.

Of course that is a jQuery thing so do the equivalent your way.

Answer (score 0):

used this for php preg_match_all()

```
$pattern = '/([\w+\._%-]+@[\w+\.-]+\.[\w+]{2,4}[^,;\s])/';
$text = 'abc@efg.com, efg, hij@emg.com, ak@efg asfbd@efg.com ab@sdfs.com abc+efg@pqr.com';
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $match);
var_dump($match);
```

```html
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(5) {
    [0] =>
    string(11) "abc@efg.com"
    [1] =>
    string(11) "hij@emg.com"
    [2] =>
    string(13) "asfbd@efg.com"
    [3] =>
    string(11) "ab@sdfs.com"
    [4] =>
    string(15) "abc+efg@pqr.com"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(5) {
    [0] =>
    string(11) "abc@efg.com"
    [1] =>
    string(11) "hij@emg.com"
    [2] =>
    string(13) "asfbd@efg.com"
    [3] =>
    string(11) "ab@sdfs.com"
    [4] =>
    string(15) "abc+efg@pqr.com"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
     function validateEmails(string) {
        var regex = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
        var result = string.replace(/\s/g, "").split(/,|;/);        
        for(var i = 0;i < result.length;i++) {
            if(!regex.test(result[i])) {
                return false;
            }
        }       
        return true;
    }
```

accepts both comma and semicolon as separator, change that if you want only comma as separator