# how to validate multiple emails in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a multiple emails seperated by commas. How to validate all these emails field using javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566396/validate-multiple-emails-comma-separated-with-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- split() the string into an array by commas
- for every array element, run the validation

What to validate in an e-mail address is a bit of a contentious topic (for example `something+xyzzy@example.museum` is actually a valid e-mail address, but most naïve validators reject it) - checking for a part before the `@`, and a probably-valid domain name after the `@` (anything separated by a dot, due to the complex mess that is TLDs these days) should be sufficient.

(why not validate the domain: you'll get it wrong. That's nothing personal, everyone gets it wrong: you, me, everyone - what with internationalized domain names, domain names longer than 4 characters, alternate DNS roots, internal domains, new domains approved each year, etc etc. If the mail bounces, too bad - but trying to validate the domain in JS is rather futile.)