# Javascript code to verify user entered the right information

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on JavaScript. This is what I have so far..

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

     function formCheck(){
      var emailFilter=/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-   Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    if (document.form.frmName.value==''){
    alert('Please enter your name');
    document.form.frmName.focus();
    document.getElementById("reqName").style.fontWeight="bold";
    return false;  
  }
      if (!(emailFilter.test(document.form.frmEmail.value))){
    alert('Please enter your email address correctly');
    document.form.frmEmail.focus();
    document.getElementById("reqEmail").style.fontWeight="bold";
    return false;
    }
    return true;
    } 
     function submitForm() [
     if (document.forms[0].firstName.value==""
     || document.forms[0].lastName.value=="") {
     window.alert("You must enter your first and last names!");
     return false;
      }
       else
     return true;
      }
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <h2>**RSVP to my Party**</h2>
    <form action="myform" method="post" name="form" onsubmit="return formCheck()">
   <table>
  <tr>
      <td><span id="reqName"> First Name:</span></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="frmName"></td>
  </tr>
  <td><span id="reqName"> Last Name:</span></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="frmName"></td>
  </tr>
  <td><span id="reqName"> Number of Guest:</span></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="NumberofGuest"></td>
  </tr>
  <td><span id="reqName"> Time Arriving:</span></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="TimeArriving"></td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
     <td><span id="reqEmail"> Email:</span></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="frmEmail">
<input type="submit" value="Send" class="submit" /></td>
  </tr>
<tr>
  <td><span id=Submit"><input type="Submit" value="Submit" /></td>
  <td><span id="reset"><input type="reset" value="Start Over" /></td>
</tr>

  </table>
  </form>

  </body>
  </html>
```

I am getting a little confused I need to get it where each code to verify that the users have enter the data into all the fields. Now do I take each field and make them each have a submit button for them to read that? I know the email one works right.

Comment: "I know the e-mail one works right" - except that **the e-mail validation is totally broken** - I can see approximately twenty false negatives (i.e. your validation will reject perfectly well-formed and valid e-mail addresses). Three most glaring examples: Welcome to 2005 - `.travel` is a completely valid TLD. Also, welcome to 2010 and IDN - `.рф` is a completely valid TLD. Also, since the 1980s, `someone+xyzzy@example.com` is a completely valid e-mail address. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566396/validate-multiple-emails-comma-separated-with-javascript/566473#566473

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your form html, call the `submitForm()` function:

```
<form action="myform" method="post" name="form" onsubmit="return submitForm();">
```

Then in your `submitForm()` function, call all the testing functions:

```
function submitForm()
{
    if (document.forms[0].firstName.value==""
        || document.forms[0].lastName.value=="") 
    {
        window.alert("You must enter your first and last names!");
        return false;
    }
    else
        // this is short for 'if nameCheck() == true && whateverCheck == true && ...'
        return formCheck() && nameCheck() && whateverCheck();
  }
```

Remark: If the user made several mistakes, you must modify the checking call to directly find all mistakes like this:

```
    //...
    else
    {
        var allOk = true;
        allOk = formCheck() ? allOk : false;
        allOk = nameCheck() ? allOk : false;
        allOk = whateverCheck() ? allOk : false;

        return allOk;
    }
```

Inside of each testing function, you can modify the field that's being tested to show errors in the user's input, e.g. by changing the `inputLabel.style.color='red'`.

**Edit:**

You should create a single, simple function for each *field type* you want to test.
Typical field types for `input type="text"` are:

- numeric field (e.g. age)
- general text field (e.g. name, street, profession, ...)
- specific data fields (examples:)

  - zip code
  - date
  - time
  - ip address
  - email

This way you will probably be able to use the same function for first and last name instead of creating two separate functions. *That also means you can take them with you to your next project instead of needing to program everything again...*

These testing functions will take an object (i.e. an input field) and return a boolean:

```
function testMyNameTextField(var testfield)
{
    // check if testfield isn't null and is valid

    var nameTextFilter = /someregexp/;
    var everythingIsOk = (testfield.value != '') && (nameTextFilter.test(testfield.value));
    testfield.style.borderColor = everythingIsOk ? '' : 'red';
    return everythingIsOk;
}
```

You can of course separate the testing and the invalid field markup into two different functions.

**Finally, for each text input field you want to test, call the appropriate testing function.**

Comment: Ok for some reason when i hit the submit button it is telling me File not found its not say you didnt enter in information in the box.. why is that?

Comment: Well, first of all, your form method file _myform_ probably doesn't exist. You need some php or such file that can do something with the data submitted. Next step would be to debug your onsubmit expression, e.g. like this: `onsubmit="var subm = submitForm(); alert(subm); return subm;"` and see if the value is actually `false`.

Comment: Ok I got it where its doesnt give me the error file but the box doesn't come up that should say enter your name if you push the send button..

Comment: That's because in your example code both first and last name fields are named _frmName_... Change that to _firstName_ and _lastName_ which you're using in your `submitForm()` function. Sometimes it's the small things. :)

Comment: Ok thank you Martin yeah I am seeing myself making a few errors i dont really need to worry just on email i need to make sure all field have data enter into them if not then the box will come up stating that.So now i am have to enter the codes to that the only question to that one will be do i have a function key to all 5 or can i group it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but look in the __Edit:__ I added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your submitForm to this

```
function submitForm() {
     if (document.forms[0].firstName.value==""
     || document.forms[0].lastName.value=="") {
     window.alert("You must enter your first and last names!");
     return false;
      }

      }
```

Call `submitForm` inside `formCheck` would make sure that the form is validated before submitted to the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have submit buttons for each of the fields. Each of those will just send all the fields to the server anyway.

To check for mistakes, you could just make the form execute a js code on submit, like this:

```
<form action="..." onsubmit="return validateData(this)">
```

Then you'd have a code like:

```
function validateData(form) {
    if (form.age.value < 0) { 
        alert("age"); return false;
    }
    // etc
    return true;
}
```

where you could use the form object that was passed as a parameter to check that the fields are correct, and return `true` iff the data is correctly formatted. If your function returns `false`, the form simply won't be submitted.

Additionally you should also execute an `alert("Field X is wrong: reason")` or something like that before returning false to let the user know why the form wasn't submitted.